# Flask : how to autenticate once and use the requests Object to all server requets

Tags: python-3.x, api, flask

im using flask and web requests when the users makes a request i internally do 2 request to third party API
for each request that is incoming, this API needs a Basic authentication.
my question is how can i set globally the Basic Authentication once.
and then use the requests object to all users :
for example, to invoke the third-party API I do :

```
username = "AA"
password ="XXX"
file_repo_api1 = f'https://api.foo.org/api/auth'
file_response1 = requests.get(file_repo_api1, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
page_json1 = file_response1.json()

file_repo_api2 = f'https://api.foo.org/api/info'
file_response2 = requests.get(file_repo_api2, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))
page_json2 = file_response2.json()
```

Can i set the "auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)" part globally ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `requests.Session` for that, as per [documentation here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/)

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('user', 'pass')
s.get('https://api.foo.org/api/info')
```

Comment: is this only for the current flask request context call ?
Or globally across application ?

Comment: Depending on where you put it I believe, if used outside of your views on module level, this should be global.

Comment: im doing it in the function that invoked per  the request